# Is the Klingon alphabet inspired by Tibetan alphabet?

Tags: star-trek, klingon-language

The Wikipedia article on the Klingon language has an unreferenced [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language#Writing_systems) that the Klingon alphabet was inspired by the Tibetan alphabet. The closest references to that statement are to [Klingon FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20041012093544/http://higbee.cots.net/~holtej/klingon/faq.htm#2.13) and [Some Comments on Orthography](https://web.archive.org/web/20061208232839/http://www.kli.org/pdf/Orthography.pdf), neither of which mention the word "Tibetan".

Are there any statements by those involved in the show indicating that this is the case?

[image]

Comment: Possibly [made up in 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Klingon_language&diff=3642323&oldid=3535247). Somebody [in 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Klingon_language&diff=15420110&oldid=14658769) didn’t like the Devanagari claim, but they left Tibetan in.

Comment: The only similarity is that they both look written by a calligraphy pen.  [Katakana calligraphy](https://en.pimg.jp/012/972/875/1/12972875.jpg) looks more similar to Klingon than Tibetan does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Klingon language was not based on any other language, but was crafted by a professional linguist, Dr. Marc Okrand, to work as its own language:

> "...the producers called on professional linguist Dr. Marc Okrand to create authentic speech for the Klingons. His task was to make their language as alien as their ridged prosthetic foreheads, while still remaining pronounceable by human actors and consistent with the battle cries from the first movie.
>
> Dr. Okrand did not base Klingon on any particular language, but drew on his knowledge of how language works to construct a wholly new language."

This isn't from Wikipedia, which is notoriously inaccurate, but from the Klingon Institute, a site dedicated to keeping the language alive, teaching the language to others, and connecting people that appreciate the language.

As for ANY connection to Tibetan, that is something never mentioned by the creator of the language. See 2) below.

As for downvoting me due to the unclear question, hmphhh.

The first source link is now corrected.

See:
1) https://www.kli.org/about-klingon/klingon-history/
2) http://www.kli.org/about-klingon/writing

Comment: The OP is not asking about the synthetic language, they're asking about the letter shapes used. e.g. [This](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Kli_piqad.GIF) vs. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_alphabet#/media/File:Tibetan_script.svg)

Comment: Actually, that's not what the question said. However, the language's creator made the language out of whole cloth, with zero reference to Tibetan, or even Cuneiform, for that matter. I added another reference link to point that out. He began with what the artists had already used in the previous Canon, and formed the rest from his own creativity.

Comment: You're mistaking the language (e.g. the sounds of the language) with the written language that was subsequently written around the language. The link between the two is really very striking.

Comment: @Valorum There's definitely a striking resemblance between the glyphs, but if the transliteration is accurate, the phonemes represented by the glyphs don't match. I'd say the glyphs may well be inspired by the Tibetan alphabet, but the Klingon alphabet as a whole (i.e. the glyphs **and** their relation to specific phonemes) probably isn't.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley - Which I think is the nub of the question. Was the person at Paramount who designed the letters inspired by the Tibetan alphabet. I'd say the answer is that they'd clearly seen it, or something very similar.

Comment: @Valorum Since the good doctor is a professional linguist, he's almost certain to have seen it. And whether conciously or {sub|un}conciously, it clearly influenced the design.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley - Except that Okrand had no hand in designing these letters. "*More recently we’ve been treated to a different alphabet, (often incorrectly attributed to Michael
Okuda, scenic designer for Star Trek: The Next Generation™),...  an
unofficial letter to a Klingon fan group from an unnamed source at Paramount resulted in the following
alphabet:*" - https://web.archive.org/web/20061208232839/http://www.kli.org/pdf/Orthography.pdf

Comment: I really don't see this so-called "striking resemblance". The Tibetan letter forms are far more complex than the Klingon and the Klingon letters are more blobbier (for lack of a better term). And none of the actual shapes are that similar either, with the sole exception—maybe, if you squint a little—of the Klingon *s* and Tibetan *ra*. Other than both having strokes with sharp points, there's really no resemblance at all.

Comment: @PatrickWynne - Well, several of them look very similar indeed. *a vs ja*, *b vs ra* (on its side), *gh vs ra*, *u vs sa* (minus the tail), etc etc.

Comment: @Valorum, the PDF you link to came from the the source I used: "(a version of this article appeared in the first issue of HolQeD,
the journal of the Klingon Language Institute, and is used here with their permission)" is stated at the very top, and the Klingon Institute is my source used. And why are you denying Okrand's involvement?. Direct from your link: "More recently we’ve been treated to a different alphabet ... one which corresponds to the phonemes of Klingon as described by **Okrand** in The Klingon Dicitionary[sic]"

Comment: I will remind everyone of the actual question: "Are there any statements by those involved in the show indicating that this is the case?"
And, as my answer stated, clearly, the answer is no. Okrand did not, at any time, state that there was any tie-in to any other language's letter shapes. Period. Saying, 'well, it looks a lot like [language A] or [language B] doesn't make it a certainty that it was taken from some other language, especially when the creator of it, Okrand, says it's not related, and was created as a whole with the use of only things that had already been in a ST series.

Comment: @Valorum Okrand =/= Okuda.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The quote makes it clear that Okrand wasn't involved in the creation of the alphabet.... and nor was Okuda.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. @MaryAnn The *phonemes* were described by Okrand, as that quote shows, but apparently not the *letters*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - For the record, I've never seen them in the same room together. So it might be like a sort of Superman/Clark Kent thing with the two of them.